# How to use both Howler.js and Wavesurfer.js together

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-audio-api, howler.js, wavesurfer.js

I'm new to HTML5 Audio programming and I recently used howler.js for my project which is an audio player based off of html5, I want the cool wave style seeker that wavesurfer.js offers to my player, but I can't find a way to use wavesurfer for my seeker and howler.js for playing the music files. Is there another jquery plugin or something that i could use to synchronize with howler,js and draw a canvas of the tracks waveform.

Comment: Almost Halloween, so let me be a necromancer:
I guess you already figured it out, but I just stumbled upon your question and needed to add that there is now audio sprite functionality in howler.
For an example see here: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/master/examples/sprite

If you insist on using both libraries, then you could create the wavesurfer object and update the position based on the progress from howler when playing the audio file.

Comment: @cmxl Similarly necro, but from what I understand, the sprite example uses a pre-generated image and doesn't actually process the audio, and it sounds like OP wants the process/render functionality of wavesurfer.

Comment: Here is a github issue from the Howler repo related to this question.
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/701